# Identifying blue dragster?

Tags: set-identification, instructions

I have bought this model as is without building instructions. So I don't know if this is an original model or a fantasy car.
I'm interested whether this is a original LEGO model, which one it is and if there are instructions available to rebuild it / let my son rebuild it.
[image: blue dragster]

I suppose it is older as there is a big figure in it (bigger than a minifig), with bendable arms.
special bricks: the motor parts are translucent
[image: pilot (bigger than minifig), translucent motor block]

Comment: This is definitely a MOC - as noted in the answer below, parts used to build it come from various sets. And looks like this was build quite long time ago with much more limited set of bricks, thus making it it great looking model in my point of view. I would clean it and keep it. Or improve slightly with period correct bricks.

Comment: It's the work of a very imaginative and talented child I'd think, as such it certainly has value...

Answer (score 5):

Inclined to think this is someone's own creation rather than an original LEGO Model.

First hint, I could identify the 2x3 slope with the X on bricklink here:
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3298pb016

And this element only seems to be available only in 3 sets, none of which are a blue dragster or even Technic sets for that matter.

Also, the sticker with the red X and the three lines is part [6567stk01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6567stk01) which [only appears in one set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6567stk01&in=S), and should be applied on a 1x6 black brick, not on blue technic liftarm.

Likewise, searching for motor blocks (both types) in sets in trans-clear color also doesn't turn up anything.

There's also quite a bit of a mismatch between the elements in the model... studded Technic, non-studded technic, city elements, old tires, new tires,...

Also, the quality of the build and aesthetics are not up to the level of an actual Lego model in my opinion...

Comment: I think it would be great to document even though it's not a "professional" model.  OP and Son can take it apart and put it back together with some improvements or make two of them.

Comment: What would you like to see documented about it ?

Comment: Thanks for that identifying, although I could imagine that one single brick would be used as spare part from another set for replacing an original one. This happend once in a set I bought in a garage sale where the instructions were included and where we in the rebuild noticed some replaced single parts (probably the original parts were lost and replaced with similar ones). Maybe the stickers with the same `X` could give some hints.

Comment: The X indicates the city subtheme "Extreme team". There are 21 sets in this subtheme according to rebrickable, none of them are dragsters of this size. There are also quite a bit of other elements to help identify this set, the wedges in blue are probably also unique enough, also the wheels...